# Redirecting to another Google Script webapp after button click

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to redirect a google app script web app onto another app script after button click. I have tried the following:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Replace document</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
}
</script>
```

The error is that google script refused to connect. When checking inspect element, it says "X-Frame Options"  to 'same-origin'.

Is there a work around on this?

I could use  tags but how do I display it after an alert?

Comment: You can't do this in the browser using `location.replace` for security reasons. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace explains: "a DOMException of the SECURITY_ERROR type is thrown. This happens if the origin of the script calling the method is different from the origin of the page originally described by the Location object..."

Comment: Is there a way to display the link instead after alert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't stop Google Apps Script from masking redirected URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685553/cant-stop-google-apps-script-from-masking-redirected-url)

Comment: @Cat In this case, the location object and the script calling the replace is from  the same domain. You can do this in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

- Trying to load `https://www.w3schools.com` in a iframe: Note that your script is served in a sandboxed iframe of different origin by Google. The `location` here refers to the sandboxed iframe @ `https://*-script.googleusercontent.com` hosted inside `https://script.google.com`. When you replace the `location`, you're replacing the inner sandboxed iframe with w3schools  website. Now, `w3schools` doesn't want to be inside `script.google.com` or any other website. So, it set it's `X-Frame Options` to `same-origin`. Some websites are ok with this. They can be embedded. w3schools isn't one of them.

```
 =============  
 |GASWebApp  |<---script.google.com[Top Frame]
 |           |  
 |=========  |  
 ||SandBox|  |  
 ||User   |<-|---- Where your html code is
 ||Frame  |  |    (*.googleusercontent.com) 
 |=========  |     [Sandboxed iFrame]
 |           |  
 =============
```

#### Solution:

- Load the web page in the top frame

#### Snippet:

```
window.top.location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
```

#### References:

- [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
- [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this handle your use case?

```js
var trigger = document.getElementById("trigger");
var link = document.getElementById("link");

trigger.addEventListener("click", showMessageAndThenShowLink);

function showMessageAndThenShowLink(){
  alert("You are about to see the link");
  link.style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
#link{ display: none; }
```

```html
<button id="trigger">Show Message</button>
<br />
<a id="link" href="https://www.w3schools.com">www.w3schools.com</a>
```

Note: In an SO snippet, clicking the link gives a "refused connection" error, but it worked fine from my desktop.