# window.location.href = window.location.href returning a blank page

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

I'm creating a webapge using Google App Script. After a button click I'm trying to reload a page and none of the below work,

1. window.location.href = window.location.href
2. window.location.reload(true)

They are redirecting to a blank page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guide to web apps in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), and [How to Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't stop Google Apps Script from masking redirected URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685553/cant-stop-google-apps-script-from-masking-redirected-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet worked

```
var url = 'myURL'
window.top.location = url
```

Comment: Better to make sure that the script contains ```<base target="_top">``` because it specifies a default target for all hyperlinks and forms on a page. `top` Opens the link in the full body of the window.