# Close or redirect tab window through using Google Apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a script that when a `if()` statement returns `false` it closes the current tab window of the google sheet or it redirects to another URL (as long as one of these work, thats ok for me).

I understand that this may be possible through using HTML but i don't know HTML well enough to do this.

I have found the below code which is meant to redirect to a different page which I tried but this does not work:

```
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
        "<form action='http://www.google.com' method='get' id='foo'></form>" + 
        "<script>document.getElementById('foo').submit();</script>");
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

See code that this is in below below:

```
  if (name == password)
  {
    Browser.msgBox('You have succesfully logged in');
    sortOutSheets();
  }
  else (name != password)
  {
    var response = Browser.msgBox('Login Failed - do you want to login again?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if(response == "yes")
      enterPassword();
    else(response == "no")
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Close Window');
  }
}
```

I have now turned to writing the HTML in another HTML file but still no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't stop Google Apps Script from masking redirected URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685553/cant-stop-google-apps-script-from-masking-redirected-url)

Comment: Sorry @TheMaster - no that doesn't.....

Comment: You say `I am trying to run a script that when a if() statement returns false it closes the current tab...` Can you show us that script?  Also what's the point of the script you did display? Is your script running client side or server?

Comment: hello @cooper - the script is only on client side and is as below.  I have now turned to trying to create the code in a html file but not exactly sure what to put!

` if (name == password)
  {
    Browser.msgBox('You have succesfully logged in');
    sortOutSheets();
  }
  else (name != password)
  {
    var response = Browser.msgBox('Login Failed - do you want to login again?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if(response == "yes")
      enterPassword();
    else(response == "no")
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Close Window');
  }`
}

Comment: Please post it in the question.

Comment: You cannot use HtmlService client side?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do.  Do you want to close a dialog, or webapp or spreadsheet?  Maybe some images would help.

Comment: looks like your're right.... just having a look at google development site: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication :( - any other ideas how i could run that?

Comment: I would really like to close the spreadsheet if at all possible.

Comment: You can't close the spreadsheet from a webapp. As a matter of fact you can't open a spreadsheet from a webapp in the same way that a user can.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I would program.

- Show Dialog box in spreadsheet asking for a password
- User enters password
- User clicks Submit button
- Client side code calls the server and sends the password to code in GS file
- Server code tests the password
- If password is good, build new HTML and open another dialog box
- The opening of a new dialog box will automatically close the first dialog box
- The new dialog box will have a `<a>` tag link in it, built with a new url on the server
- When the new dialog box opens, automatically run code with `window.onload = function() {var aTagElement; aTagElement = document.getElementById('idOfLinkTag');aTagElement.click() }`
- The client code will automatically run when the dialog box opens, and programmatically click the link, which will open a new file in the same browser tab

Comment: Thanks @Alan Wells - will have a look and see if I can create something based on that.  May have to do quite a bit of research first as I'm not all that literate with html!